# How to redirect the countdown of the jCounter plugin after the end only once, without infinite loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the Jcounter plugin http://devingredients.com/jcounter/ on a project, it's perfect for what I need, except for a problem I'm facing. I need it when I finish the countdown, it updates the same page only once, without giving infinite loop. How can I do this?

The callback function seems to give this possibilide, would I need some control? I have little experience in jquery.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
  <title>jCounter - jQuery plugin - devingredients.com</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.jCounter-iosl.css">
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.jCounter-0.1.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
        //first counter
        $(".countdown1").jCounter({
            animation: "slide",
            date: "2017/10/13 19:53:20",
            format: "dd:hh:mm:ss",
            twoDigits: 'on',

            callback: function() {
                window.location.href = "index.php?block=Yes"
             }

         });

        });
</script>
```

```
   <div class="iosl-theme-wrapper countdown1">
    <div class="iosl-theme">
        <ul>
            <li><p><span><em><b class="days">00</b><i class="daysSlider"><u>00</u><u>00</u></i></em></span></p></li>
            <li><p><span><em><b class="hours">00</b><i class="hoursSlider"><u>00</u><u>00</u></i></em></span></p></li>
            <li><p><span><em><b class="minutes">00</b><i class="minutesSlider"><u>00</u><u>00</u></i></em></span></p></li>
            <li><p><span><em><b class="seconds">00</b><i class="secondsSlider"><u>00</u><u>00</u></i></em></span></p></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="jC-clear"></div>
        <p class="jCtext">
            <span><em class="textSeconds">SEGUNDOS</em></span>
            <span><em class="textMinutes">MINUTOS</em></span>
            <span><em class="textHours">HORAS</em></span>
            <span><em class="textDays">DIAS</em></span>
        </p>
        <div class="jC-clear"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
  **jquery.jCounter-0.1.4.js**

/**********************************
* jCounter Script v0.1.4 (beta)
* Author: Catalin Berta
* Official page and documentation: http://devingredients.com/jcounter
* Licensed under the MIT license
**********************************/

;(function($,document,window,undefined) {
//once upon a time...
$.fn.jCounter = function(options,callback) {
var jCounterDirection = 'down'; // points out whether it should count down or up | handled via customRange setting

var customRangeDownCount; //if true, it will tell countdown_proc() it's a down count and not an up count
    var days,hours,minutes,seconds;
    var endCounter = false; //stops jCounter if true
    var eventDate; //time target (holds a number of seconds)
    var pausedTime; //stores the time (in seconds) when pausing
    var thisEl = this; //custom 'this' selector
    var thisLength = this.length; //number of multiple elements per selector

    var pluralLabels = new Array('DAYS','HOURS','MINUTES','SECONDS'); //plural labels - used for localization
    var singularLabels = new Array('DAY','HOUR','MINUTE','SECOND'); //singular labels - used for localization

    this.options = options; //stores jCounter's options parameter to verify against specified methods
    this.version = '0.1.4';

    //default settings
    var settings = {
        animation: null,
        callback: null,
        customDuration: null,
        customRange: null,
        date: null,
        debugLog: false,
        serverDateSource: 'dateandtime.php', //path to dateandtime.php file (i.e. http://my-domain.com/dateandtime.php)
        format: 'dd:hh:mm:ss',
        timezone: 'Europe/London',
        twoDigits: 'on'
    };

    //merge the settings with the options values
    if (typeof options === 'object') {
        $.extend(settings,options);
        thisEl.data("userOptions", settings); //push the settings to applied elements (they're used by methods)
    }

    if(thisEl.data('userOptions').debugLog == true &&  window['console'] !== undefined ) {
        var consoleLog = true;  //shows debug messages via console.log() if true
    }

    //METHODS
    var jC_methods = {
        //initialize
        init : function() {
            thisEl.each(function(i,el) {
                initCounter(el);
            });
        },
        //pause method: $.jCounter('pause')
        pause : function() {
            if(consoleLog) { console.log("(jC) Activity: Counter paused."); }
            endCounter = true;
            return thisEl.each(function(i,el) {
                clearInterval($(el).data("jC_interval"));
            });
        },
        //stop method: $.jCounter('stop')
        stop : function() {
            if(consoleLog) { console.log("(jC) Activity: Counter stopped."); }
            endCounter = true;
            return thisEl.each(function(i,el) {
                clearInterval($(el).data("jC_interval"));
                $(el).removeData("jC_pausedTime");
                resetHTMLCounter(el);
            });
        },
        //reset method: $.jCounter('reset')
        reset : function() {
            if(consoleLog) { console.log("(jC) Activity: Counter reset."); }
            return thisEl.each(function(i,el) {
                clearInterval($(el).data("jC_interval"));
                resetHTMLCounter(el);
                initCounter(el);
            });
        },
        //start method: $.jCounter('start')

        start : function() {
            if(consoleLog) { console.log("(jC) Activity: Counter started."); }
            return thisEl.each(function(i,el) {
                pausedTime = $(el).data("jC_pausedTime");
                endCounter = false;
                clearInterval($(el).data("jC_interval"));
                initCounter(el);
            });
        }
    }

    //checks whether customDuration is used
    if(thisEl.data("userOptions").customDuration) {
        if(!isNaN(thisEl.data("userOptions").customDuration)) {
            var customDuration = true;
        } else {
            var customDuration = false;
            if(consoleLog) { console.log("(jC) Error: The customDuration value is not a number! NOTE: 'customDuration' accepts a number of seconds."); }
        }
    }

    //checks whether customRange is used
    if(thisEl.data("userOptions").customRange) {    
        var customRangeValues = thisEl.data("userOptions").customRange.split(":");
        var rangeVal0 = parseInt(customRangeValues[0]);
        var rangeVal1 = parseInt(customRangeValues[1]);
        if(!isNaN(rangeVal0) && !isNaN(rangeVal1)) {
            var customRange = true;
            if(rangeVal0 > rangeVal1) {
                var customRangeDownCount = true;
            } else {
                var customRangeDownCount = false;
                jCounterDirection = 'up';
            }
        } else {
            var customRange = false;
            if(consoleLog) { console.log("(jC) Error: The customRange value is not a valid range! Example: customRange: '0:30' or '30:0'"); }
        }
    }

    //checks whether animation is set to slide
    if(thisEl.data("userOptions").animation == 'slide') {   
        thisEl.data("jCanimation","slide");
    }

    //FUNCTIONS

    //jCounter initializer
    function initCounter(el) {
        if(customDuration) {
            if (pausedTime) {
                if (!isNaN(pausedTime)) {
                    eventDate = Math.round(pausedTime);
                }
            } else {
                eventDate = Math.round($(el).data("userOptions").customDuration);
            }
            currentTime = 0;
            countdown_proc(currentTime,el);
            $(el).data("jC_interval", setInterval(function(){
                if(endCounter == false) {
                    currentTime = parseInt(currentTime) + 1;
                    countdown_proc(currentTime,el)
                }               
            },1000));
        } else if(customRange) {
            eventDate = Math.round(customRangeValues[1]);
            if (pausedTime) {
                if (!isNaN(pausedTime)) {
                    var currentTime = eventDate - pausedTime;
                }
            } else {
                var currentTime = Math.round(customRangeValues[0]);
            }
            countdown_proc(currentTime,el);
            $(el).data("jC_interval", setInterval(function(){
                if(endCounter == false) {
                    var ifRangeDownCount = (customRangeDownCount) ? currentTime = parseInt(currentTime) - 1 : currentTime = parseInt(currentTime) + 1;
                    countdown_proc(currentTime,el);
                }               
            },1000));
        } else {
            eventDate = Date.parse($(el).data("userOptions").date) / 1000;
            dateSource = thisEl.data("userOptions").serverDateSource + '?timezone=' + thisEl.data("userOptions").timezone + '&callback=?';
            $.ajax({
                url: dateSource,
                dataType : 'json',
                data : {},
                success : function(data, textStatus){
                    var currentDate = Date.parse(data.currentDate) / 1000;
                    startCounter(currentDate,el);
                },
                error : function(){
                    if(consoleLog) { console.log("(jC) Error: Couldn't find dateandtime.php from serverDateSource: " + thisEl.data('userOptions').serverDateSource + "\n(jC) - Make sure the path is correct! \n(jC) - Now using the client-side time (not recommended).") }
                    var currentDate = Math.floor($.now() / 1000);
                    startCounter(currentDate,el);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    function startCounter(currentDate,el) {
        countdown_proc(currentDate,el);
        if (eventDate > currentDate) {
            $(el).data("jC_interval", setInterval(function(){
                if(endCounter == false) {
                    currentDate = parseInt(currentDate) + 1;
                    countdown_proc(currentDate,el)
                }               
            },1000));
        } else {
            resetHTMLCounter(el)
        }
    }

    //jCslider - adds the slide effect layer
    //Note: this requires a jCounter slide-ready theme! (i.e. iOS dark or iOS light)
    function jCslider(el,unitClass,timeUnit,eventDate,duration) {
        $(el).find(unitClass + " u").each(function(i,el) {
            var twoDigits = (thisEl.data("userOptions").twoDigits == 'on') ? '0' : '';
            var newIndex = (jCounterDirection == 'up') ? newIndex = -i : newIndex = i;      
            currNo = parseInt(timeUnit,10) + (newIndex);
            if (String(parseInt(timeUnit,10)).length >= 2) { 
                $(el).text(parseInt(timeUnit,10) + (newIndex))
            } else if(String(parseInt(timeUnit,10)).length == 1 && currNo == 10) {
                $(el).text(parseInt(timeUnit,10) + (newIndex))
            } else {
                $(el).text(twoDigits + (parseInt(timeUnit,10) + (newIndex)));
            }
        })
        $(el).find(unitClass).animate({
            top: '0.15em'
        },200, function() {
            $(el).find(unitClass + " u:eq(1)").remove();
            $(el).find(unitClass).prepend('<u></u>');
            $(el).find(unitClass).css({'top':'-1.24em'})                    
        });
    }

    //resets jCounter's HTML values to 0 or 00, based on the twoDigits setting
    function resetHTMLCounter(el) {
        if(thisEl.data("userOptions").twoDigits == 'on') {
            $(el).find(".days,.hours,.minutes,.seconds").text('00');
        } else if(thisEl.data("userOptions").twoDigits == 'off') {
            $(el).find(".days,.hours,.minutes,.seconds").text('0');
        }
        if(thisEl.data("jCanimation") == 'slide') {
            $(el).find(".daysSlider u,.hoursSlider u,.minutesSlider u,.secondsSlider u").text('00');
        }
    }

    //main jCounter processor
    function countdown_proc(duration,el) {
        //check if the counter needs to count down or up
        if(customRangeDownCount) {
            if(eventDate >= duration) {
                clearInterval($(el).data("jC_interval"));
                if(thisEl.data("userOptions").callback) {
                    thisEl.data("userOptions").callback.call(this);
                }
            }

        } else {
            if(eventDate <= duration) {
                clearInterval($(el).data("jC_interval"));
                if(thisEl.data("userOptions").callback) {
                    thisEl.data("userOptions").callback.call(this);
                }
            }
        }

        //if customRange is used, update the seconds variable
        var seconds = (customRange) ? duration : eventDate - duration;

        var thisInstanceFormat = thisEl.data("userOptions").format;

        //calculate seconds into days,hours,minutes,seconds
        //if dd (days) is specified in the format setting (i.e. format: 'dd:hh:mm:ss')
        if(thisInstanceFormat.indexOf('dd') != -1)  {
            var days = Math.floor(seconds / (60 * 60 * 24)); //calculate the number of days
            seconds -= days * 60 * 60 * 24; //update the seconds variable with no. of days removed
        }
        //if hh (hours) is specified
        if(thisInstanceFormat.indexOf('hh') != -1)  {
            var hours = Math.floor(seconds / (60 * 60));
            seconds -= hours * 60 * 60; //update the seconds variable with no. of hours removed
        }
        //if mm (minutes) is specified
        if(thisInstanceFormat.indexOf('mm') != -1)  {
            var minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
            seconds -= minutes * 60; //update the seconds variable with no. of minutes removed
        }
        //if ss (seconds) is specified
        if(thisInstanceFormat.indexOf('ss') == -1)  {
            seconds -= seconds; //if ss is unspecified in format, update the seconds variable to 0;
        }

        //conditional Ss
        //updates the plural and singular labels accordingly
        if (days == 1) { $(el).find(".textDays").text(singularLabels[0]); } else { $(el).find(".textDays").text(pluralLabels[0]); }
        if (hours == 1) { $(el).find(".textHours").text(singularLabels[1]); } else { $(el).find(".textHours").text(pluralLabels[1]); }
        if (minutes == 1) { $(el).find(".textMinutes").text(singularLabels[2]); } else { $(el).find(".textMinutes").text(pluralLabels[2]); }
        if (seconds == 1) { $(el).find(".textSeconds").text(singularLabels[3]); } else { $(el).find(".textSeconds").text(pluralLabels[3]); }

        //twoDigits ON setting
        //if the twoDigits setting is set to ON, jCounter will always diplay a minimum number of 2 digits
        if(thisEl.data("userOptions").twoDigits == 'on') {
            days = (String(days).length >= 2) ? days : "0" + days;
            hours = (String(hours).length >= 2) ? hours : "0" + hours;
            minutes = (String(minutes).length >= 2) ? minutes : "0" + minutes;
            seconds = (String(seconds).length >= 2) ? seconds : "0" + seconds;
        }

        //updates the jCounter's html values
        if(!isNaN(eventDate)) {
            $(el).find(".days").text(days);
            $(el).find(".hours").text(hours);
            $(el).find(".minutes").text(minutes);
            $(el).find(".seconds").text(seconds);

            if(thisEl.data("jCanimation") == 'slide') {
                $(el).find(".daysSlider u:eq(1)").text(days);
                $(el).find(".hoursSlider u:eq(1)").text(hours);
                $(el).find(".minutesSlider u:eq(1)").text(minutes);
                $(el).find(".secondsSlider u:eq(1)").text(seconds);
                jCslider(el,'.secondsSlider',seconds,eventDate,duration); 
                if(parseInt(seconds,10) == 59) { 
                    jCslider(el,'.minutesSlider',minutes,eventDate,duration) 
                    if(parseInt(minutes,10) == 59) { 
                        jCslider(el,'.hoursSlider',hours,eventDate,duration) 
                        if(parseInt(hours,10) == 23) { 
                            jCslider(el,'.daysSlider',days,eventDate,duration) 
                        }
                    }
                }   
            }
        } else { 
            if(consoleLog) { console.log("(jC) Error: Invalid date! Here's an example: 01 January 1970 12:00:00"); }
            clearInterval($(el).data("jC_interval"));
        }
        //stores the remaining time when pausing jCounter
        $(el).data("jC_pausedTime", eventDate-duration);
    }



    //method calling logic
    if ( jC_methods[this.options] ) {
        return jC_methods[ this.options ].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
    } else if ( typeof this.options === 'object' || ! this.options ) {
        return jC_methods.init.apply( this, arguments );
    } else {
        console.log('(jC) Error: Method >>> ' +  this.options + ' <<< does not exist.' );
    } 

}
//the end;
}) (jQuery,document,window);
```

Comment: because your callback redirects the page. Make your callback do something else to the page itself. You should also consider using a different library since the very first thing on the page you linked is "This library is no longer maintained"

Comment: Cfreak do you know any current library to tell me? And what would your idea for a callback for the same page? Please, I really need a tip.